# boost asio - closing serial port

Tags: c++, boost

I use boost asio serial port and ioservice which is run on the separate thread:

```
ioServiceThread = std::thread(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &ioService));
```

I need to implement a callback which closes and opens serial port again.
I wonder how should I close serial port. Here is first version:

```
if (serialPort.is_open())
{
     ioService.post(boost::bind(&SerialPortAccess::DoClose, this, boost::system::error_code()));
}

//iosService.stop() ?

if (ioServiceThread.joinable())
{
     ioServiceThread.join();
}

//ioService.reset() ?

void DoClose(const boost::system::error_code& error)
{
     if(!(error.message().empty()))
     {
          //throw some exception ?
     }

     serialPort.close();
}
```

Second version:

```
if (serialPort.is_open())
{
     serialPort.close();
}

//iosService.stop() ?

if (ioServiceThread.joinable())
{
     ioServiceThread.join();
}

//ioService.reset() ?
```

I guess that if I use post method (first version) some undone tasks (serial port reading/writing) will be done before closing serial port, right ? Should I throw an exception from DoClose method when an error message is not empty ? Does that error may imply that serial port can't be closed ? Should I call stop and reset on ioservice ?